# Refund Totals not show in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, totals, refund

I'm using **Magento ver. 1.9.3.2** and I have no idea why **Refund Totals** not get shown in **Magento**, and I don't know what I need to do to resolve it.

[image]

```
2017-11-28T13:19:44+00:00 ERR (3):  Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Subtotal in /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/app/Mage.php:595 Stack trace: 0 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28754): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...') 1 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28696): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Mage_Adminhtml_...', Array) 2 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28731): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/sales...', 'subtotal') 3 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28498): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/sales...', 'subtotal') 4 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28464): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 5 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28465): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 6 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28465): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 7 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28465): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 8 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28465): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 9 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28465): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 10 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(28469): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 11 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(14260): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks() 12 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(14185): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks() 13 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true) 14 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreditmemoController.php(233): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout() 15 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(14334): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreditmemoController->newAction() 16 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(18813): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new') 17 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(18343): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 18 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/includes/src/__default.php(21279): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 19 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 20 /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store') 21 {main}
```

AND `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('creditmemo_totals') ?>` show null in

```
app\design\adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/cr‌​editmemo/create/item‌​s.phtml
```

Comment: Have you chheck consol or error log file for this? And if any third party extesnio used for order then try to disable that extension and then check.

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya : yes but nothing show in log file.

Comment: Any Third Party Extension create issue?

Comment: yes, **Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Subtotal in /var/www/vhts/bsus.es/wehn.bsus.es/app/Mage.php:595**

Comment: @ Dhiren Vasoya : **<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('creditmemo_totals') ?>** show null in **app\design\adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/creditmemo/create/items.phtml** do you have any idea about it ?